# Custom Page Templates for a complex application - code must sit in a plugin and not the Theme

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, page-template

I am developing a custom set of applications which sit on top of a WordPress site.

The theme is developed by a third party, and I have decided it is time to remove the custom page templates from the theme / child theme, and put them properly into my own plugin.

I really don't like the "*copy your page templates from the plugin to the custom theme when your plugin is enabled, and remove them when the plugin is disabled*" method as per [Is it possible for a plugin to register a page template file?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/24940/is-it-possible-for-a-plugin-to-register-a-page-template-file/25017#25017)

Is the Shortcode API the best there is? At least I can create the hooks for [custom_dashboard] and [custom_login] etc etc.  I assume I can enqueue scripts and styles as needed.

Or is there a better method? Something new in WordPress that I missed??

Edit: All of this work is just for one site, and if I / we ever white-label the solution then we will supply the existing theme from the third party or tailor the css to fit.  Most of the CSS & Javascript is either from the plugin or from a dependency, such as datatables.js or intro.js.  Copying the extra css & js to the theme doesn't help either, so it will all go into the plug with a dependency manager and proper enqueueing or or I will just stop using WordPress for anything other than the header and footer

Comment: Templates are theme territory as I strongly suggest to stay with that. No two themes uses the same styles and HTML markup which makes compatibility an impossible quest.

Comment: OK, I will edit my question